# How to Insert a Line Break in Java SWT Without Breaking Text?

Tags: java, string, sockets, swt, line-breaks

So, the title might be a bit confusing, but here's the dilemma. So, often times I've seen this code not working correctly for me:

`message.setText(message.getText() + "\nHello world!");`

The point of that is to get the current text, break the line, and then put in "Hello world!". And sometimes it adds a line break, sometimes it doesn't. This in general, is super annoying, but that's not the main problem today (it relates though).

What I'm doing, is having a server get all of the files in a directory, write them to a file, then convert that file to a list, where at each value, it adds a line break and that value to a string (please excuse my overly-repetitive method). Like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    stringLines += fileLines.get(i);
    stringLines += "\n";
}
```

Then I send all that over to my client, where it puts it into a multi-line textbox. And it works... without the line break there. With that added \n code, it only shows the first line of the string (or only transmits the first line, I'm not sure). However, when taken out, it does work. But it's completely unacceptable to have 50 directory names placed right next to each other without separation.

So I'd like to know why this is happening, and how to fix it. Solutions I tried were I looked up line seperation techniques, like `System.getProperty("line.separator");`, but they did the same thing as \n.

Comment: What type is `message` in your example?

Comment: @nitind `message` is a multi-line textbox.

Comment: By "type" I was asking for the fully qualified class name.

Comment: `\n` works fine in a `Text` control with `SWT.MULTI` style - is that what you have? You need to check exactly what your client is receiving and putting in the control

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can help debug.